# Cisco настройка списков доступа

Tags: сеть, cisco, cisco-packet-tracer

Пытаюсь настроить список доступа для двух Пк (Один пк админа, другой юзера)

Пк админа должен пинговать юзера, а юзер соответственно не должен.
На скрине пк админа (ip 15.0.0.4) юзер (13.0.0.2)

Написал для следующие access-list:

list3 стоит на in в интерфейсе Eth 0/1/0

```
10 permit ip host 13.0.0.2 host 15.0.0.3
20 permit ip host 13.0.0.3 host 15.0.0.3
30 permit ip host 13.0.0.4 host 15.0.0.3
40 permit ip host 13.0.0.5 host 15.0.0.3
50 permit ip host 13.0.0.5 host 11.0.0.5 (4 match(es))
60 permit ip host 13.0.0.5 host 12.0.0.5 (4 match(es))
70 permit icmp 15.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 host 13.0.0.2 echo
80 permit icmp host 13.0.0.2 15.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 echo-reply
```

list4 стоит на in в интерфейсе Eth 0/0/0

```
20 permit icmp host 13.0.0.2 15.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 echo-reply
30 deny icmp host 13.0.0.2 15.0.0.0 0.0.0.255 echo
```

Во время пинга на обоих пк ловлю Destination host unreachable.

В чем может быть ошибка?

Ссылку на проект прилагаю
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PyA04E5FYQh1m165j2GhC6zLy1X5ai44?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создал отдельный проект, там делал по такому принципу (пример для подсети 10.0.0.0)

```
Extended IP access list INT_IN
10 permit icmp host 192.168.0.2 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 echo
20 permit icmp 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 host 192.168.0.2 echo-reply

Extended IP access list INT_OUT
10 deny icmp 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 host 192.168.0.2 echo
20 permit icmp 10.0.0.0 0.255.255.255 host 192.168.0.2 echo-reply
```